# How to prevent that v-img was called when refreshing the page?

Tags: image, vue.js, vuetify.js, render

**The problem-**

As the title mentioned, I try to call the image only once, even I refresh the same page because that's the same image.

**My code-**

```
<template>
  <v-img>
    height="450"
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/10480463/pexels- 
    photo-10480463.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
    lazy- 
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/10877192/pexels-photo-10877192.jpeg"
    class="d-none d-md-block"
    alt="001"
  </v-img>
</template>
```

**Addition to the quesiton-**

If you fetch images from store, use asyncData can do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the re-rendering of this image element when the Vue component updates then you can use the [v-once directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once).
`v-once` make sure the element will not be re-rendered after it has been rendered initially, so when Vue.js processes data changes, it will simply ignore the element. This can be used to optimize update performance.

```
<template>
  <v-img v-once src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></v-img>
</template>
```

Now, for page reload case, I assume your concern is the performance. So, you can cache the images for fast loading. Here is a guide to [use cache in the Vue](https://blog.logrocket.com/frontend-caching-in-vue-with-workbox-service-workers/).